# I am using following code to download pic from local host. It results in unexpected error

Tags: java, android

when I run a following code

```
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

         final String urlString = "http://10.0.2.2/conn/s.png";
            // URL newurl = null;

                     try{   
                do
                {
                            if (ch==1)
                            {
                                //Thread.sleep(7000);
                                HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(new URL(urlString).toURI());
                                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
                                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                                BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
                                    InputStream is = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                                   im.destroyDrawingCache();
                                    im.setImageBitmap(bitmap);   
                                    bitmap=null;
                                   // Thread.sleep(3000);
                                    out.write(1);
                                   out.flush();




                                 }  
                }
                while(( ch=in.read()) == 1);
                     }
                     catch(IOException ex)
                     {

                     }
                    catch(URISyntaxException ex)
                    {}
    }
};
```

and the thread is initialized like this:

```
                  t = new Thread(r);
          t.start();
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(ImageView.java:306)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(ImageView.java:320)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at remote.presentation.rshare$1.run(rshare.java:124)
03-18 01:20:50.399: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: Can u post your complete exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the UI from a thread, can't do that in Android. It has to be done on the UI thread. I prefer AsyncTasks to using Threads. This AsyncTask will get an image from a url.

The class

```
private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    private ImageView view;

    public GetImage(ImageView iv){
         this.view = iv;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    //background thread
        try {

            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return null;

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap b){
        if(b != null)
            this.view.setImageBitmap(b); 
    }
}
```

to use it

```
new GetImage(myImageView).execute(someURL);
```

**EDIT** (reason for edit, see comments) - the following code will repeatedly download the same image as the question asker wanted

Create a class variable for the GetImage class

```
GetImage getImageInstance = new GetImage(myImageView); 
getImageInstance.execute(url);
```

Modified class

```
private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Bitmap,Void>{

    private ImageView view;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    long lastUpdateTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public GetImage(ImageView iv){
         this.view = iv;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                    //background thread
        while(running){
            try {
                //if more than 2 seconds have elapsed update the image
                if((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastUpdateTimestamp) > 2000){
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(params[0]).getContent());
                    pubilshProgress(bitmap);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return null;

    }
    //this method that will update the UI
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... images){
        if(images[0] != null)
            this.view.setImageBitmap(images[0]);
        lastUpdateTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
    public void stopDownloading(){
        running = false;
    }
}
```

To stop downloading

```
getImageInstance.stopDownloading();
```

I don't know what your app does but users will not like downloading unnecessary images which eats into their data allowance, perhaps think about a better way to do what you want to do.

Comment: triggs how can i stream image file contineously after every 3 seconds

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "stream an image".

Comment: i want to download image from server after every 2 seconds and show on screen using image view

Comment: do you mean something like: you have an array of image urls and you want to download one of them, set it to the imageview, wait 2 seconds then download the second image and set it to the imageview, etc.

Comment: no i want to download same pic again and again and pic will be updated as well

Comment: I don't know what exactly your app does but users wont like an app that uses up their data allowance unnecessarily but see my edited answer for how you would go about doing what you want